# How can I set Date format when use power shell to generate date and save to batch variable?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I use this command in batch for generate curentdate -1 and save it to variable in batch but How can I put format in `ToString()` I already use ' and "

```
for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('powershell "$date = Get-Date; $date=$date.AddDays(-1);$date.ToString();"') do set var=%a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :

```
for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('powershell "$date = Get-Date; $date=$date.AddDays(-1);$date.ToString('yyyy:MM:dd');"') do set var=%a
```

Here are the specificators :

```
Spécificator    Type                       Example      Output Example
dd              day                        dd           10
ddd             Name of the day            ddd          Jeu.
dddd            Complet name of the day    dddd         Jeudi
f, ff, …        Fractions of seconds       fff          932
gg, …           position                   gg           ap. J.-C.
hh              Hour two digits            hh           10
HH              Hour two digits (24 hours) HH           22
mm              Minuts 00-59               mm           38
MM              Month 01-12                MM           12
MMM             Month shortcut             MMM          Sep.
MMMM            complet name of the month  MMMM         Septembre
ss              Seconds 00-59              ss           46
tt              AM or PM                   tt           ““
yy              Years, 2 digits            yy           02
yyyy            Years                      yyyy         2002
zz              Time zone, 2 digits        zz           +02
zzz             Complete Time zone         zzz          +02:00
:               Separator                  hh:mm:ss     10:43:20
/               Separator                  dd/MM/yyyy   10/12/2002
```